# Record-Locking in Access 10

Tags: ms-access, networking, multi-user

I am using MS Access 10 in a multi-user environment.  The DB is split with tables in the back end (stored on a network drive), and everything else in the front-end (stored on about five different computers).

Some of the front-end computers are using Access 07, but the DBs were created in the 07 format. I have checked that the database is NOT using the 2010 encryption, and all the other 10 settings that are not compatible with 07. In fact, the 07 computers will run the DB just fine when alone... the problem is when more than one person logs into the DB.
Often there is a "Too Many Active Users" error when trying to sign in. Other times, users are able to log-in and open forms, but whenever changes are made we get "locked" errors. (This happens on all computers, not just the ones running 07).

All the DB copies have record-level locking, but it behaves as if it is locking the entire table. I have checked, and none open the DB in "exclusive" mode. (When you go to the navigation pane, and open the table, the table itself will not allow new entries).
I have tried creating the forms based on queries and also with filters instead. I get the same locking problems either way (Does anyone know if queries or filters lock data differently?).

This is forcing the DB to be used by one user at a time, when multiple people need access. Is there anything I am overlooking? All have permissions set to the network drive, I removed the "compact on close", I tried converting to an ACCDE file (the ACCDE file will not open in 07, only 10, but we get the same locking errors).
Can anyone think of what I might be missing here?

Comment: have you tried upgrading the 07 users to 10?  Is it only the 07 users which cause locking errors?